# How to airbnb superset login using curl command?

Tags: curl, apache-superset

I am going to use the curl command to get a list of superset dashboards.

So first I have to login from superset.
But I can not login well.

How do I handle login with the curl command?

Below is the login curl command.

```
curl -i --data 'userName=admin&password=123456&csrf_token=ImEwODdjNzc4YjFmMGIyMjk5YTY3Y2YxYzNlYTA0YTc1MjY1NDBkYTIi.DAHvaA.TCOgcoCQ6IVkpfIvm2ABjzfXYic' -X POST "http://{supersetURL}/login/"
```

response body

```
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
Server: gunicorn/19.6.0
Date: Wed, 24 May 2017 15:10:41 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 150

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The CSRF session token is missing.</p>
```